# Hackerrank - "Sherlock and the Beast"

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I solved the problem but for two test cases, it's giving me timeout error. It's taking longer than 2 seconds on their servers. I tried using `<ctime>` to calculate the run time of the program and on my system, it's taking between 1.3-1.6 seconds. It's only giving me error for TestCases #9 and #10.

[The question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-the-beast) is to find the largest *N*-digit "decent" number, where a decent number consists only of the digits '3' and '5', and the number of threes is divisible by 5, and the number of fives is divisible by 3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string decent_number(int, std::string);

int main() {
  clock_t start = clock();
  int numOfCases;

  std::cin >> numOfCases;
  int n;
  for (int i = 0; i < numOfCases; ++i) {
    std::string dn("-1");
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int j = n; j >= 0; --j) {
      if (j % 3 == 0 && (n-j) % 5 == 0) {
        dn = decent_number(j, "5");
        dn += decent_number(n-j, "3");
        break;
      }
    }
    std::cout << dn << std::endl;
  }
  clock_t ends = clock();
  std::cout << "Time: " << static_cast<double>(ends - start)/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC
            << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

std::string decent_number(int repeatNum, std::string num) {
  std::string dn;
  for (int i = 0; i < repeatNum; ++i)
    dn = dn + num;
  return dn;
}
```

The code is simple, I check for the number of 3s and 5s which make the number and call a string builder function which builds the string.

Comment: [Related question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43709/sherlock-and-the-beast)

Comment: I don't remember this problem, but apparently I've solved it at some point. Just by looking at my accepted submission and cross-referencing I'd say you ditch all those string operations. You can easily solve the problem without them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is clearly caused by that `decent_number` function of yours. Once you have the number of `'5'` digits and  the number of `'3'` digits, just dump the number to the console - building an `std::string` to hold it is totally redundant:

Your program currently takes `Time: 1.71979` on my system when running `Test 9` (which fails in the HackerRank test environment).
If instead of building that string you simply print the digits it takes: `Time: 0.026608`.

Alternatively you could simply build the whole strings from the start (instead of using the loop to append one character at a time) - this works even faster: `Time: 0.000818`.

```
dn = std::string(j, '5');
if (n-j) {
    dn += std::string(n-j, '3');
}
```